# SQL change data format for minimum and maximum values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have attendance data coming to me in this format:

```
EmployeeId |    Date    |   Time   |
--------------------------------------
        1  | 01/01/2015 | 14:01:35 |
        2  | 01/01/2015 | 13:00:00 |
        1  | 01/01/2015 | 17:35:37 |
        1  | 01/01/2015 | 18:01:35 |
        2  | 01/01/2015 | 19:14:12 |
        1  | 01/02/2015 | 14:21:42 |
        2  | 01/02/2015 | 15:12:03 |
        1  | 01/02/2015 | 15:42:20 |
```

I need this data in the following format:

```
EmployeeId |    Date    | FirstTime | LastTime |
--------------------------------------------------
        1  | 01/01/2015 | 14:01:35  | 18:01:35 |
        2  | 01/01/2015 | 13:00:00  | 19:14:12 |
        1  | 01/02/2015 | 14:21:42  | 15:42:20 |
        2  | 01/02/2015 | 15:12:03  | 15:12:03 |
```

`FirstTime` is the `Min(Time)` for that `date/employee` and `lasttime` is the `max(time)` for that `date/employee`. I have removed Auto increment PK for simplification.

I can't wrap my head around how to do that. I was thinking `Pivot` might be the way to go but I couldn't use it to the desired effect. Can you give me some help on how to do that?

Comment: The post title doesn't match description. You don't want to convert rows to columns?

Comment: Yes. I will correct that. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
select employeeid, date, min(time) as firsttime, max(time) as lasttime
from tablename
group by employeeid, date
```

You can group by employeeid and select the min and max time for a given day.

Comment: Thanks. It was so easy and simple and yet completely skipped my mind. Thumbs up.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Pivot, here is example:

```
CREATE TABLE Product(Cust VARCHAR(25), Product VARCHAR(20), QTY INT)
GO
-- Inserting Data into Table
INSERT INTO Product(Cust, Product, QTY)
VALUES('KATE','VEG',2)
INSERT INTO Product(Cust, Product, QTY)
VALUES('KATE','SODA',6)
INSERT INTO Product(Cust, Product, QTY)
VALUES('KATE','MILK',1)
INSERT INTO Product(Cust, Product, QTY)
VALUES('KATE','BEER',12)
INSERT INTO Product(Cust, Product, QTY)
VALUES('FRED','MILK',3)
INSERT INTO Product(Cust, Product, QTY)
VALUES('FRED','BEER',24)
INSERT INTO Product(Cust, Product, QTY)
VALUES('KATE','VEG',3)
GO
-- Selecting and checking entires in table
SELECT *
FROM Product
GO
-- Pivot Table ordered by PRODUCT
SELECT PRODUCT, FRED, KATE
FROM (
SELECT CUST, PRODUCT, QTY
FROM Product) up
PIVOT (SUM(QTY) FOR CUST IN (FRED, KATE)) AS pvt
ORDER BY PRODUCT
GO
-- Pivot Table ordered by CUST
SELECT CUST, VEG, SODA, MILK, BEER, CHIPS
FROM (
SELECT CUST, PRODUCT, QTY
FROM Product) up
PIVOT (SUM(QTY) FOR PRODUCT IN (VEG, SODA, MILK, BEER, CHIPS)) AS pvt
ORDER BY CUST
GO
```

Relative link: [link](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/06/07/sql-server-pivot-and-unpivot-table-examples/)